# Redirect user if they are not logged in

Tags: redirect, actions

If user enters the url www.abc.com in the browser and he is not logged in, then we want to redirect him to www.abc.com/de. How can I do this within WordPress?

Answer (score 3):

```
function redirect_user() {    
   if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'www.abc.com/' ) {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
           wp_redirect( 'http://www.abc.com/de/' );
           exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_user' );
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: But this need to be added into a function, and this function should be added before an action right? something like this: add_action('some_action', 'this_function'). What should be that 'some_action'?

Comment: I think it's ok on `init`, I've updated the code.